# how to use netbeans 7 to develop an application who need netbeans platform 6x?

Tags: java, netbeans, rcp

i would like to know if we can use netbeans 7 to develop a program who need netbeans platform 6x?

in netbeans, there is a place to add netbeans platform but i'm not able to add any netbeans platform.

any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a NetBeans 6.x version installed (unzipped) somewhere alongside your main NetBeans 7 so you can choose the NetBeans 6.x folder when selecting a custom NB platform.

Comment: i tired that sometime i get strange behaviour, like module missing